# Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from uint32 to address requested. I tried typecasting it but still doesn't wk

Tags: data-types, type-casting

```
cyborg@DESKTOP-S7TDG7E:~/solidity-course/foundry-f23/foundry-smart-contract-lottery-f23$ forge test --mt testFulfillRandomWordsPicksAWinnerResetAndSendsMoney -vvvv
[⠑] Compiling...
[⠔] Compiling 6 files with 0.8.19
[⠘] Solc 0.8.19 finished in 8.19s
Error: 
Compiler run failed:
Error (9553): Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from uint256 to uint64 requested.
  --> script/DeployRaffle.s.sol:41:13:
   |
41 |             entranceFee,
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^

Error (9553): Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from uint256 to bytes32 requested.
  --> script/DeployRaffle.s.sol:42:13:
   |
42 |             interval,
   |             ^^^^^^^^

Error (9553): Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from address to uint256 requested.
  --> script/DeployRaffle.s.sol:43:13:
   |
43 |             vrfCoordinator,
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Error (9553): Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from bytes32 to uint256 requested.
  --> script/DeployRaffle.s.sol:44:13:
   |
44 |             gasLane,
   |             ^^^^^^^

Error (9553): Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from uint64 to uint32 requested.
  --> script/DeployRaffle.s.sol:45:13:
   |
45 |             subscriptionId,
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Error (9553): Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from uint32 to address requested.
  --> script/DeployRaffle.s.sol:46:13:
   |
46 |             callbackGasLimit
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**The code.**

```
//SPDX-Lisence-identifier:MIT

import {Script} from "forge-std/Script.sol";
import {Raffle} from "../src/Raffle.sol";
import {HelperConfig} from "./HelperConfig.s.sol";
import {CreateSubscription, FundSubscription, AddConsumer} from "./interaction.s.sol";

pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

contract DeployRaffle is Script {
    function run() external returns (Raffle, HelperConfig) {
        HelperConfig helperConfig = new HelperConfig();
        (
            uint256 entranceFee,
            uint256 interval,
            address vrfCoordinator,
            bytes32 gasLane,
            uint64 subscriptionId,
            uint32 callbackGasLimit,
            address link
        ) = helperConfig.activeNetworkConfig();

        if (subscriptionId == 0) {
            // we are going to need to create a subscription
            CreateSubscription createSubscription = new CreateSubscription();
            subscriptionId = createSubscription.createSubscription(
                vrfCoordinator
            );

            // Fund it
            FundSubscription fundSubscription = new FundSubscription();
            fundSubscription.fundSubscription(
                vrfCoordinator,
                subscriptionId,
                link
            );
        }

        vm.startBroadcast();
        Raffle raffle = new Raffle(
            entranceFee,
            interval,
            vrfCoordinator,
            gasLane,
            subscriptionId,
            callbackGasLimit
        );
        vm.stopBroadcast();
        AddConsumer addConsumer = new AddConsumer();
        addConsumer.addConsumer(
            address(raffle),
            vrfCoordinator,
            subscriptionId
        );
        return (raffle, helperConfig);
    }
}
```